# PRTweenOperation timingFunction member not found in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to use the PRTween library in a Swift iPhone app.

Original example code from GitHub:

```
PRTweenPeriod *period = [PRTweenPeriod periodWithStartValue:100 endValue:200 duration:3];
PRTweenOperation *operation = [[PRTweenOperation new] autorelease];
operation.period = period;
operation.target = self;
operation.timingFunction = &PRTweenTimingFunctionLinear;
```

My Swift port:

```
var period = PRTweenPeriod.periodWithStartValue(100, endValue: 200, duration: 3) as PRTweenPeriod
var operation = PRTweenOperation()
operation.period = period
operation.target = self
operation.timingFunction = PRTweenTimingFunctionLinear
```

Xcode is giving me this error:

```
'PRTweenOperation' does not have a member named 'timingFunction'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. I can clearly see the member definition in PRTween.h. I'm thinking it might be related to the fact that this is where the definition of PRTweenTimingFunction takes me.

```
typedef CGFloat(*PRTweenTimingFunction)(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat);
```

Has anyone else seen an error like this? Any suggestions for fixes?

P.S. I'm not really sure what to call that typedef. Is it a function pointer?

EDIT

As a workaround, I used this code that does not ask for a timing function:

```
let period = PRTweenPeriod.periodWithStartValue(100, endValue: 200, duration: 2) as PRTweenPeriod

PRTween.sharedInstance().addTweenPeriod(period, 
    updateBlock: { (p: PRTweenPeriod!) in
        NSLog("\(Int(p.tweenedValue))"
    }, 
    completionBlock: { NSLog("Completed tween") })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a function pointer. This is a current limitation of [C interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13):

> Note that C function pointers are not imported in Swift.

You might consider [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if you'd like this to work. (Note that block-based APIs are fine and work with Swift closures.)